# System differential equation check correct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the system differential equation
>
> $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y-z}=\frac{dz}{y+z}$$

I think:

$$\frac{dy}{y-z}=\frac{dz}{y+z}$$

$$(y+z)~dy = (y-z)~dz$$

$$y^2 + z^2 = C_1$$

And then I do not know how to solve it.

---

Maybe:

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{ydy}{y^2-yz}+\frac{zdz}{yz-z^2}$$

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{d(y^2+z^2)}{2(y^2+z^2)}$$

$$lnx=\frac{ln(y^2+z^2)}{2} + C_2$$

$$x^2=(y^2+z^2)C_2$$

Is that correct?

Comment: $y^2 + z^2 = C_1$ is false. $x^2=(y^2+z^2)C_2$ is correct. I suppose all this comes from a problem of PDE.  To check it, is should be necessary that you edit the PDE, and conditions if they are given.

Answer (score 0):

$(y+z)dy=(y-z)dz$ translates to
$$
\frac12d\ln(y^2+z^2) = \frac{ydz-zdy}{y^2+z^2}=Im\left(\frac{dy+i\,dz}{y+iz}\right)=d\arg(y+iz)
$$
so that $|y+iz|=C·e^{\arg(y+iz)}$ which can be parametrized as $y+iz=C·e^{(1+i)\phi}$, $C\in\Bbb R$.

---

Combining the other two identities in to give the same complex numbers gives
$$
(dy+i\, dz)=[(y-z)+i\,(y+z)]\,\frac{dx}x=(1+i)(y+iz)\,d\ln|x|
$$
which allows to identify $\phi=\ln|x|$.

Thus $y=Cx\cos(\ln|x|)$ and $z=Cx\sin(\ln|x|)$.